This message is sent outside of allowed window - FB Graph API
A few weeks ago, our app was approved with the following permissions:
instagram_business_manage_messages, instagram_manage_comments, instagram_manage_messages, instagram_business_manage_comments
and this is our login url with scopes, example  -
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?third_party=re&client_id=867763&redirect_uri=oauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=business_basic%2Cbusiness_manage_messages%2Cbusiness_manage_comments%2Cbusiness_content_publish

Our use case is as follows: when someone comments on our post with a matching keyword specified in our backend, we send a reply to that comment and simultaneously send a direct message (DM) to the user.
However, we're facing an issue where only 1 out of 100 comments successfully sends both the comment reply and DM. In other cases, the comment replies are sent consistently, but the DM fails with the error: "This message is sent outside of allowed window." This occurs 99% of the time.
Given that we have access to the Business API, we are unsure why we are facing this issue. Could you please advise?
this is the
error: {
  error: {
    message: 'This message is sent outside of allowed window.',
    type: 'IGApiException',
    code: 10,
    error_subcode: 2534022,
    fbtrace_id: 'ASeWzBS_LCXn'
  }
}

same error code mentioned on fb docs
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/error-codes
We tried with different multiple accounts but same error, but when a user first sends a message to owner of insta post then again comments on post then it sending comment and dm successfully.

You can't reply to a comment with a DM. "Apps can only send a message to a customer within 24 hours of receiving the customer's message."

@ceejayoz it is possible, and it workings for us sometimes,
this is docs for this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/features/private-replies

"Only one message can be sent to the person who commented" may imply that your public comment counts, and the 1/100 that succeed are people who already DMed the page. Have you tried making the private reply first, then the public?

@ceejayoz , I didnt understand Have you tried making the private reply first, then the public?

You say "we send a reply to that comment and simultaneously send a direct message". Have you tried reversing the order you do these two actions? Send the DM first?

@ceejayoz , Yes i tried with reversing the order like first comment then DM, it didnt work , so i again tried with first DM then comment, but same result

You're right! It's allowed to send a DM in response to each comment. However, the message is not sent through the usual method: you need to specify as "comment_id" field the value received by webhook callback in the "recipient" property instead of "id" field, normally used. It will work without any issues.
Wrong way:
recipient: { id: FROM-ID }

Correct way:
recipient: { comment_id: COMMENT-ID }

